# "Perforce" sync to specific folder or Change Root

Tags: directory, synchronization, perforce

I want to sync folder by using cmd.

First I login Perfoece.

```
p4 set P4CHARSET=utf8
p4 set P4PORT={Server}
p4 set P4USER={myID}
p4 set P4CLIENT={mySpace}
p4 set P4PASSWD={myPAW}
```

then I have two question,

1. Is there cmd to sync folder to specific folder (not at root)??

   sync -f {Folder} @{label}

   always sync them to ROOT.
2. If can't, how can I change ROOT by cmd..?

   I can only change them when I type [P4 client] and edit the txt.

   But I want to do them all by cmd,

   Anyone can help me~

Answer (score 0):

The location of the repository files on your workstation is controlled by the workspace view and workspace root in the 'p4 client' specification; you cannot override this with 'p4 sync' option flags.

You can retrieve a single file with 'p4 print' and place it into any location on your local machine using the '-o' flag, but this isn't the same thing as 'p4 sync' at all.

If you want the repository files to go into a different location, you need to update your client root, as you've already noticed. You do that by taking the output of 'p4 client -o', modifying that output to set a different view mapping, workspace root, etc., and then send that output into 'p4 client -i'.

So:

```
p4 client -o | sed 's:/my/old/root:/new/root/location:g' | p4 client -i
```